# Running a Visual Studio C++ 2017 compiled executable inside a Windows Docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-container

I am trying to dockerize a simple C++ Hello-World application (Release Build) compiled using Visual Studio C++ 2017.

The Hello World application only prints a line to the console, writes to a dummy file, and goes into an infinite loop. It works completely fine on my machine which has VC15 runtimes already installed, and VS2017 working.

I am using the base image **microsoft/windowsservercore:1803**, spinning up a container, and copying the very same application to be inside it. I've tried with multiple attempts, but the application just fails to launch. To be sure I also copied entire VC runtimes manually from my system to the container, and also installed the VC Runtimes inside the container.

Here's the Dockerfile i am using:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:1803

SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe C:\vc_redist.x64.exe

COPY ["hello-world.exe", "C:/hello-world.exe"]

RUN Start-Process C:\vc_redist.x64.exe -ArgumentList '/quiet' -Wait ;
RUN Start-Process C:\hello-world.exe
```

I've tried to run a powershell inside the container, and manually launch the executable. But just nothing happens. There are no logs, no traces or anything else.

How do i get this executable to launch up? This is the only file that i am using in the VS Project to create the executable:

```
// hello-world.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n","Hello World!");
    std::FILE* f1;

    if (fopen_s(&f1, "./temp_output.txt", "w"))
    {
        std::array<int, 3> v = { 42, -1, 7 }; // underlying storage of std::array is an array
        fwrite(&v, sizeof(int), static_cast<int>(v.size()), f1);

    }
    while (1){ }

}
```

The set of commands to manually launch the executable inside the container:

```
1. docker build -t windows-server-core-1803 -f Dockerfile .
2. docker run <Imageid>
3. docker exec -it <ImageId> powershell
4. PS >> .\hello-world.exe
```

Comment: Maybe try inspecting `(Start-Process C:\hello-world.exe -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode`

Comment: can you add this line in your docker file `ENTRYPOINT["hello-world.exe"]` and try again

Comment: I see nothing happening. Tried both approaches @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: @Kundan The run step simply ran and exited normally. No output any where. Where can i get any logs regarding process failure?

Comment: Put some logs in exe itself ao that you know if exe was executed.

Comment: @Kundan The exe has code in it to open a temporary text file and write to it. I've added a log as well at the top. None of the two instructions execute.

Comment: @Kundan See the .cpp file I've added above.

Comment: Did you manage to answer this question?  I'm having the same trouble...

Comment: I was able to solve it by hit and trial. The issue occurred due to missing dependencies due to which the program didn't start up inside the container. I carefully pruned the dependencies which were needed by my program and copied them inside the container. Suggest you to copy Windows/System32 and Windows/SysWOW64 from your local machine to inside the container (add it as a build step in dockerfile), to start with, since Windows Server base images usually are a lightweight version of Windows, and have a lot of core Win related DLLs missing.

Answer (score 0):

referencing my docker images and Dockerfile
I make "Hello Docker" program with c++, VS2017, console and place helloDocker.exe file on same Dockerfile folder

hub:
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/jykim0824/hellodockerwithvcredist

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/F/6DF3FF94-F7F9-4F0B-838C-A328D1A7D0EE/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe 

RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet

WORKDIR C:\mydir 

COPY . . 

CMD helloDocker.exe
```